# Replicating pre-calculated views in CouchDB/Couchbase

Tags: couchdb, couchbase

When i first query a CouchDB/Couchbase view it needs to be calculated. This can take a good while if there are large number of docs and that for each single view..

Is there any way of replicate an already calculated view from one Couch to another?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly through CouchDB replication, no, there's all sorts of practical complexities in how that would have to be implemented that make it impractical I'm afraid.

For starters it means that CouchDBs have to carefully manage replication of view calculation of changes simultaneously somehow exactly in sync with the actual data (so you don't ever get newer view calculations than data), and that then gets further complicated by the fact that views only get updated when requested, so view data on either end could be out of date (and if users are querying with stale=ok, it might even be required to stay out of date).

I believe you can do it by directly copying the view index files (in /var/lib/couchdb/.DBNAME_design/SOMEHASH.view by default I think), if you just need a once-off view sync. I'd recommend against doing that frequently as a general solution though, since it's not officially supported AFAIK and is likely to be pretty fragile.

Comment: oh, thats awesome thanks. However didn't mention i need the pre-indexed views in Couchbase Lite, which is a single file with .touchdb extension, so i guess your solution is not valid for my particular case. Anyway thanks for the interesting information

Answer (score 0):

This isn't directly the answer to your question, although as PimTerry pointed out, replicating the view index is not supported, especially between different implementation.

What you can do instead is follow the procedure described here:

http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/How_to_deploy_view_changes_in_a_live_environment

This way you can have your couchdb calculate the new index "in background" without blocking the usage of your application.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Link is broken.